# How can we show that if $f(n) = O(n^2)$, then $ f(n) = O(n^3)$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm looking at the 'positive constants' definition, but just not seeing how to go from here to there.

Comment: Hint: $n^2\le n^3$, for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition $f(n)=\mathcal O(n^2)$ if and only if there's $N$ and $C$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $|f(n)|\le C n^2$. In this case clearly we have
$$\forall n\ge N,\quad |f(n)|\le C n^3$$
so it suffices to take the same constant.

Comment: what does ∀n mean?

Comment: for all $n$ ...

Comment: 70k...right on the mark!!